# How to manage large number of files in Pending Changes windows in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I have large number of changed files in my Pending Changes windows and I don't want to check-in these changes to TFS. Every time that I want to check-in my new changes I should find my changed files from these large number of files. How can I manage these files for example to folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is, "Undo the checkout."

The less obvious answer is to use [shelvesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can shelve the changes that you're not ready to commit yet, and unshelve them at a later point in time.

Comment: I just made some changes to test and understand the code. These changes aren't useful for other one and I don't want to undo these changes at this time.

Comment: Then use a shelveset.

Comment: I want to have these changes in my local, but I want to see them in my Pending Changes window when I want and not always.

Comment: Also I have some local changes that I need them to run the source code in my local computer.

Comment: You're pretty much asking for two things that are mutually exclusive. "I want to have a bunch of files checked out, but I don't want to see that they're checked out." The VS2012 has a more robust version of the Pending Changes window that lets you include/exclude files and folders easily, but VS2010 doesn't have anything equivalent.

Comment: include and exclude, these are the exactly things that I want. Thank you so much Daniel. Sorry if my question was ambiguous.